# FormBuilder how to reverse content of a ChoiceList

Tags: php, symfony4, formbuilder

Actually I create a ChoiceType (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) from an EntityType and I want to reverse the recovered data.

```
$formMapper
        ->with('Niveau', ['class' => 'col-md-12'])
        ->add('number', EntityType::class, array('required' => true, 'label' => 'NUMBER',
            'class' => Number::class,
            'choice_label' => 'info',
        ))
        ->end();
```

example : I get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and I want [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] in my ChoiceList.

Is there a way to sort by DESC instead of ASC ? Should I call a request from NumberRepository ?

Comment: This example might be helpful - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: Thank you, that was what I wanted ! Can you answer to the post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need in your case:

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => User::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities